# how to Check/Uncheck com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.CheckBox programmatically (gxt2.2.1)

Tags: gwt, extjs

I'm using extjs gwt (gxt2.2.1). I'm using the CheckBox widget. I need to have various CheckBox widgets check/uncheck, get disabled/enabled based on certain logic. I can get the enabling disabling part but not check/uncheck. The com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.CheckBox (not extjs version) used to have setChecked() (it's deprecated now). I need a similar functionality for the extjs gwt version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `setValue(java.lang.Boolean value)`
 method. For more details refer to [CheckBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CheckBox.html#setValue%28java.lang.Boolean%29)